# SQL Server - Set a bit variable using SELECT CASE WHEN, but default it to 0 if the SELECT returns no records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the following statements currently. How can I accomplish this logic with just one statement?

```
DECLARE @DisableCSDSync BIT

SET @DisableCSDSync = (SELECT 
                           CASE WHEN PropertyValue = 'true' 
                              THEN 1 
                              ELSE 0 
                           END 
                       FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK) 
                       WHERE Property = 'DisableSync' AND ParentId = 61040)

IF @DisableCSDSync IS NULL 
    SET @DisableCSDSync = 0
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `PropertyValue` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value when declaring the variable, so that the variable will have the default value in case there is no row fetched by your select query. Also, set the value in the select statement to prevent value from going to null if there are no rows to be fetched like this:

```
DECLARE @DisableCSDSync BIT = 0

SELECT @DisableCSDSync = CASE WHEN PropertyValue = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Property = 'DisableSync' AND ParentId = 61040
```

Comment: I like the answer, but could this also be done with `COALESCE`?

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you expected output even if select returns no records

```
DECLARE @DisableCSDSync BIT

SET @DisableCSDSync = ISNULL((SELECT CASE
                                       WHEN PropertyValue = 'true' THEN 1
                                       ELSE 0
                                     END
                              FROM   MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
                              WHERE  Property = 'DisableSync'
                                     AND ParentId = 61040), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following

```
DECLARE @DisableCSDSync BIT = ISNULL(TRY_CAST((
                   SELECT PropertyValue
                   FROM   MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
                   WHERE  Property = 'DisableSync'
                          AND ParentId = 61040) AS BIT), 0);
```

It uses the same `ISNULL` approach as one of the other answers to deal with the zero row case but also uses the same `ISNULL` (in conjunction with `TRY_CAST .. AS BIT`) to deal with the `ELSE` branch of the `CASE`.

The semantics are not *exactly* the same in that if `PropertyValue` is `1` it will be treated as `true` with the above approach but likely they are close enough.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @DisableCSDSync BIT

Set @DisableCSDSync = isnull( 
(SELECT Max( CASE WHEN PropertyValue = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Property = 'DisableSync' 
AND ParentId = 61040 )
,0)

Isnull will grant a default value 0 when you dont receive any record.
The max will make sure you only receive 1 record. Multiple record will give you an error !